# How to make a python program loop back to a certain line

Tags: python

I have the following code and I would like it to jump back to a line if a certain eventuality were to occur:

```
number_of_10ct = int(input("How many 10 Cent coins would you like to insert? "))
while number_of_10ct < 0:
    number_of_10ct = int(input("Please enter a positive number."))
number_of_20ct = int(input("How many 20 Cent coins would you like to insert? "))
while number_of_20ct < 0:
    number_of_20ct = int(input("Please enter a positive number."))
number_of_50ct = int(input("How many 50 Cent coins would you like to insert? "))
while number_of_50ct < 0:
    number_of_50ct = int(input("Please enter a positive number."))
number_of_100ct = int(input("How many 1 Rand coins would you like to insert? "))
while number_of_100ct < 0:
    number_of_100ct = int(input("Please enter a positive number."))
number_of_200ct = int(input("How many 2 Rand coins would you like to insert? "))
while number_of_200ct < 0:
    number_of_200ct = int(input("Please enter a positive number."))

number_of_500ct = int(input("How many 5 Rand coins would you like to insert? "))
while number_of_500ct < 0:
    number_of_500ct = int(input("Please enter a positive number."))

# Creating a variable to store the total amount of
# money inserted into the vending machine.
change = round(((number_of_10ct * 0.10) +
                (number_of_20ct * 0.20) + 
                (number_of_50ct * 0.50) + 
                (number_of_100ct * 1.00) +
                (number_of_200ct * 2.00) +
                (number_of_500ct * 5.00)),
               2)
# Informing the user how much they have entered in total.
print("\n")
print ('You have a credit of' ,change, 'ZAR')

while change > 0:
    customer_choice = input(("What would you like to buy?"
                             "Type N when you are finished \n"))
    if (customer_choice == "Kleiner Brauner" or
        customer_choice == "kleiner brauner" and
        change >= product_1_price):
        print ("You have chosen a", product_1,
               "these cost", product_1_price, "each,")
        change = round((change - product_1_price),2)
        print ("You have this much money remaining: R", change)
    elif (customer_choice == "Kakao" or
          customer_choice == "kakao" and
          change >= product_2_price):
        print ("You have chosen a", product_2,
               "these cost", product_2_price, "each,")
        change = round((change - product_2_price),2)
        print ("You have this much money remaining: R", change)
    elif customer_choice == "N" or customer_choice == "n":
        break
    elif change <= 0:
        print ("You have run out of money.")
        break
    else:
        print ("There has been an error or you may not have enough credit.")
```

What I would like to happen is: if `change = round((change - product_1_price),2)` would end up being negative, then I would like the program to return to the top (`number_of_10ct = int(input("How many 10 Cent coins would you like to insert? "))`) and allow the user to enter more "money".

How can I do that?

Comment: It is a little bit hard to read this code as it's quite wide. I would suggest following [Python's PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) that recommends limiting the number of characters per line to 79. You can do so by putting your expressions between brackets or parentheses most of the time, as said in the PEP 8.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is put all your code in an extra `while` loop that would keep running until `change` becomes positive (so you would need to initialise `change` to a negative value before the loop).

```
change = -1

while change < 0:
    # All the rest of your code (re-indented to be under this while loop)
```

With this, you will enter your `while change > 0` loop after change has been set to the good value. Once `change` becomes negative, then you get out of this loop and go back at the top, where the user can add coins.

Then, if the customer decides to buy nothing before using all their change, then `change` is still positive, and you get out of the main `while change < 0` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop and a [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) statement:

```
while True:
  dostuff()
  if goback():
    continue  # back to start of loop
  else:
    break     # code after the loop
```